# 3n+1 weird stuff happening

Tags: c

While simulating the [Colatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) problem i have made recursion when i want to print the count number in the recursion i get the result i need but when the function return the result it gives me weird numbers, why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int divide(int n,int count){

    if(n<=1){printf("%d ",count);return count;} 

    if(n%2==1){divide(n=3*n+1, ++count);}
    else{divide(n/=2, ++count);}
}
int main(void) {  
    printf("%d ",divide(10,1)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW: I don't think that Collatz is actually solved yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to *return* the results of the recursive calls:

```
if (n % 2) { return divide(3 * n + 1, count + 1); }
//           %%%%%%
else       { return divide(n / 2, count + 1); }
```

Note that there's no point in assigning to the local variables, so I've changed that to simple computations.

Comment: I would suggest adding "-Wall" or similar 'warn everything' to the compiler flags. That should pick up "not all paths have a return value".

Answer (score 10):

You don't have any default `return`. So the return value is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

A. you need to return the returned value from the recursion calls.
B. why do you assign a value to `n` in the calls to divide?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int divide(int n,int count){

    if(n<=1){printf("%d ",count);return count;} 

    if(n%2==1)
    {
        return divide(3*n+1, ++count);
    }
    else
    {
        return divide(n/2, ++count);
    }
}
int main(void) {  
    printf("%d ",divide(10,1)); 
    return 0;
}
```